# CSS properties with conditional styles and falsy values

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm looking for the answer to the question how should I use styles with conditional operators.

What code example would be the best? Can we use non-CSS values such as `undefined`, `null`, `false`, etc.?

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : undefined
```

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : 'initial'
```

> [image]

Is it okay to use it in that way? (so we pass 'undefined' and 'null' as a css property)

```js
margin: isOpen ?? '10px'
```

and one more (so we pass every falsie value)

```js
margin: isOpen && '10px'
```

or maybe this

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : ''
```

As context we can say we wanna use it in react `style` porp, or in `styled-components`

Comment: Indirectly related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: This might also depend on your intent here; where that logic related part comes into play/how it might be set/derive from

Answer (score 1):

Use `unset` to reset the property to its inherited value. More on the subject here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

The way you design your if else statement would be unopinionated, as long as you don't set an `undefined` or `null` or any value not allowed for margin, all is good.

Answer (score 0):

style vs styled-components
Two Scenarios:

1. If you are creating Components where you are going to reuse it. Such as Material UI Textfield components (Commonly same component used for entire project ) in this scenario go with styled components.
2. If you are using any div or span or any element for specific UI. Which is for a single specific task and you are sure that you are not going to reuse. Then probability go with style tag. And if you want to you can also uses classes and make sure that css class is not defined at 2 styles.css files.

margin: isOpen ? '10px' : undefined

instead of undefined use 'unset' so that in future you can check the details via developer tools if required.

margin: isOpen ?? '10px'

Never use this what if you get isOpen as true

then margin is true which is a invalid property

margin: isOpen && '10px'

never use && what if isOpen is null. again invalid property

**
go with unset which would be a best option

> margin: isOpen ? '10px' : 'unset'

**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).